# Is it problematic to repeat the same import in multiple modules?

Tags: python, python-import

I am writing modules right now and several of these import `numpy`. For example, the simplest kind of module just creates a namespace:

```
import numpy as np
pi=np.pi
```

Here, I have to `import numpy` – but I also have to `import numpy` for my main program and other modules to actually use `numpy` directly. *Is this problematic, for example does it occupy additional memory?*

My assumption is that no space is left occupied, because even though I import numpy in my main program, it complains if I don't do so in the module. So I guess the import of numpy is "unloaded" (not sure if correct vocabulary) as soon as my main program has finished importing my own module.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Is this problematic?" - Do you have problems with this? `numpy` is imported only once even though it is imported in different modules. It does take up space as much as one numpy module. Python is smart enough to make this process optimal (enough). If you want to know more, try looking this question up.

Comment: Note that the file you run initially is your main *module*, not your main *program*. You have to separately `import numpy` in each module because they represent separate *namespaces*, not separate *programs*. All *modules* live inside the same *program* (unless you explicitly spawn another, e.g. via `multiprocessing`) and there is no concept of one module being "finished" executing/importing like a program and then automatically freed.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych The "problematic" formulation was actually an edit by a mod. I did not write this. Your comment is helpful, but I don't understand the "Do you have problems with this?" attitude. 1. Only once it causes problems I should worry about possibly faulty code? 2. The question was more asked out of interest, because I simply want to know better what python does when I tell it to do something. I did not expect to run into problems. I just didn't want to have dumb code.

Comment: Please note that no moderators have edited this question.  The user who edited it is a normal user with reputation-based privileges.  Moderators have a diamond next to their name, like mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has separate concepts of *importing* and *loading* a module:

- *loading* actually creates an in-memory representation of the module. This may run arbitrary code, create arbitrary objects, and produces a `module` object.
- *importing* only *binds* a module in the current namespace. The module is fetched from an interpreter-global storage, which may *load* the module if it is not present.

Practically speaking, this means that Python will load `numpy` only the first time `import numpy` executes. Afterwards, `numpy` is fetched from [an internal storage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules).<sup>1</sup> *The memory is not duplicated for repeated `import`s.*

The binding done by `import` is like a regular name-binding, i.e. `import numpy as np` behaves like `np = __magic_import_function__("numpy")`. When done at the top-level of a module, the name will persist for as long as the module lives – usually as long as the program. *Repeated imports consume no more memory than simple name bindings.*

---

<sup>1</sup> It is possible to access and modify this internal storage as well as the import machinery. This makes it technically possible that modules are re-loaded on `import`. This is highly unusual and can be ignored for practical purposes unless a module explicitly uses this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module in Python, first it checks if there are more equal import statements on the code. If so, it doesn't reimport all the module content again, because it could take a lot of memory and time, it just gets a reference to the already created object with all the constants, functions, and objects of the module, in this case `numpy`.

Also, if you want more details about how Python imports modules, you can take a look at the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem).