# In Python, do repeated imports of a module create duplicate references in memory?

Tags: python, memory, module, static, singleton

In a program I am writing, I have a module that contains *many* imports, constants, and functions. This module is used in a class that there exist *many* instances of. Given the code below, when I create an instance of *MyClass*, are the references within *my_module.py* being duplicated in memory? In other words, after *main.py* runs, does *my_module.x* and *my_module.y* exist in 3 separate locations in memory?

If that is the case, what's the best approach to avoid this? Should I convert *my_module* into a giant singleton or static class?

**my_module.py**

```py
import numpy
import time
    
x = 100
y = 200
    
def some_func():
    pass
    
# assume many more variables/funcs/imports
```

**my_class.py**

```py
import my_module
    
class MyClass():
    # makes use of my_module
```

**main.py**

```py
class1 = MyClass()
class2 = MyClass()
class3 = MyClass()
# do other things...
```

Comment: I believe the answer you're looking for is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72785061/is-it-problematic-to-repeat-the-same-import-in-multiple-modules

Comment: If you use the "import" statement, a module will only be loaded once.

Comment: You can research this yourself by making a module that is imported by many others and the module just has `print('loaded!')` in it. Every time you see `"loaded!"` you could potentially have memory allocations.